# Change Text color by cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that is doing some calculating of tickets that is garbing data from another cell. The client is asking if some colors can be used for the lines that contain the ticket information.

Here is the formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("2-Day Friday/Saturday ", P2 & CHAR(10) , "1-Day Friday ", R2 & CHAR(10) ,"1-Day Saturday ", T2 )
```

The client would like the calculation the text for 1-Day Friday to be bold and red, The 1-Day Sat to be bold and yellow and the 2 day passes to be bold in blue. Is this possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: You would need to use VBA for that

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking for multiple text colours in one cell, or for a whole line to be coloured based on the value of one cell?  In the latter case, conditional formatting can do the job, but if it's the first (which seems to be what you're asking) I'm not sure it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply more than one style setup in the same cell.

Excel can only display one colour at any given time, within any given cell.

I mean... your cell can't be formatted like 50% bold and 50% italic. Or 1 word yellow, 1 blue and 1 red... Styles are applied to the whole cell content.

***But...***

You can achieve what you want by using `multiple cells` in the same row, with different rules of `conditional formatting` for each state of nature that you want.

In your example, more precisely, you'll have:

```
    A                         B
1   2-Day Friday/Saturday     P2
2   1-Day Friday              R2
3   1-Day Saturday            T2
```

This way your `multiple cells` will represent one "cell" and you can set their formatting conditionally via VBA.